# JQuery Validate: Custom message not working

Tags: jquery-validate

```
      rules: {
        email           :   {
            required        :   true,
            email           :   true,
            remote: {
                    url: SITE_URL + 'index.php?sign_up/emailValidate',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                      email: function() {
                        return $("#email").val();
                      }
                    }
                  }

        }

      },
      message:{
           email:   {
                required        :   "Email cant be empty.",
                email           :   "Please enter a valid email",
                remote          :   "This email already exists."

            }
      }
```

Comment: I had this problem once too and never figured it out. I gave up and wrote a custom `$.addMethod`. I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: i couldnt figured it out too. I have been using a `$.addMethod`, but this way must easier for everything.

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo in your code. You should use 'messages' instead of 'message'.

```
messages:{
           email:   {
                required        :   "Email cant be empty.",
                email           :   "Please enter a valid email",
                remote          :   "This email already exists."

            }
```

Comment: I bet I did the same thing way back when I couldn't get that working. Is it possible the jQuery docs had the typo in it too, I'm almost sure I checked every possible detail against their sample.