# jQuery Validate - custom message not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to create a custom error message for the 'required' rule.
It should be easy [using the 'messages' parameter to the validate method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#code).
But I can't seem to figure out why my code is not working.

I forked the fiddle from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378472/jquery-validate-can-i-re-validate-a-group-of-fields-after-changing-one) into [this new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eSgus/).

Can anybody spot the error?

PS. Same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337789/jquery-validate-custom-message-not-working), except in my case it's not the typo.

EDIT: migrated fiddle code here.
HTML:

```
<form action="get">
    <div><input type="text" name="part1" class="part"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="part2" class="part"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="part3" class="part"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="part4" class="part"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
    var valid = $(options[1], element.form).filter(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).length >= options[0];

    if(!$(element).data('reval')) {
        var fields = $(options[1], element.form);
        fields.data('reval', true).valid();
        fields.data('reval', false);
    }
    return valid;
}, jQuery.format("Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        part1: { required: true },
        part2: { require_from_group: [2,".part"] },
        part3: { require_from_group: [2,".part"] },
        part4: { require_from_group: [2,".part"] }
    },
    messages: {
        required: "THIS MESSAGE IS NOT WORKING"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. Add the code just below the rules section

```
messages:{
                field name:{
                    required:"Please enter a value"                     
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the field to associate with the message. Your code:

```
messages: {
    required: "THIS MESSAGE IS NOT WORKING"
}
```

Should be:

```
messages: {
    part1: "THIS MESSAGE IS NOT WORKING"
}
```

I forked a fiddle from [your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/eSgus/) into [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/EwBkH/).